# merging two dataframes while moving column positions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `df1` that is:

```
               0
103773708  68.50
103773718  57.01
103773730  30.80
103773739  67.62
```

I have another one called `df2` that is:

```
               0
103773739  37.02
103773708  30.25
103773730  15.50
103773718  60.54
105496332  20.00
```

I'm wondering how I would get them to combine to end up looking like `df3`:

```
               0      1
103773708  30.25  68.50
103773718  60.54  57.01
103773730  15.50  30.80
103773739  37.02  67.62
105496332  20.00  00.00
```

As you can see sometimes the index position is not the same, so it has to append the data to the same index. The goal is to append `column 0` from `df1`, into `df2` while pushing `column 0` in `df2` over one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 result = df1.join(df2.rename(columns={0:1})).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Just swap `df1` with `df2`, else you will miss out index `105496332`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply merge on index, and then relabel the columns:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')
df.columns = [0,1]
df = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: df.columns = [1,0]

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.columns = ['1']         # Rename the column from '0' to '1'. I assume names as strings.
df=df2.join(df1).fillna(0)  # Join by default is LEFT

df
               0      1
103773739  37.02  67.20
103773708  30.25  68.50
103773730  15.50  30.80
103773718  60.54  57.01
105496332  20.00   0.00
```